# error: no matching function for call to 'sort(..., ..., <unresolved overloaded function type>)'

Tags: c++

I declare and then define a function that performs a comparison:

```
  template <class KEY, class VALUE>      
  bool compareFlatMapElements(
              typename SortedPairsVector<KEY, VALUE>::ElementType& first, 
              typename SortedPairsVector<KEY, VALUE>::ElementType& second);
        // Compares the specified 'first' and 'second' using
        // 'bsl::less<KEY>' to compare the values stored in 'first()' of
        // each pair held by the 'FlatMap_Element.

  template <class KEY, class VALUE>
  inline
  bool compareFlatMapElements(
              typename SortedPairsVector<KEY, VALUE>::ElementType& first, 
              typename SortedPairsVector<KEY, VALUE>::ElementType& second)
  {
      return first.data().first < second.data().first;
  }
```

I then later try to use it in a sort

```
      std::sort(d_data.begin(), d_data.end(), compareFlatMapElements);
```

What is causing the following error and how do I fix it?

```
error: no matching function for call to 'sort(..., ..., <unresolved overloaded function type>)'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no free standing function `compareFlatMapElements` without the template parameters.

If the key type of `d_data` is `Key` and value type of `d_data` is `Value`,

Use

```
std::sort(d_data.begin(), d_data.end(), compareFlatMapElements<Key, Value>);
```